# Matched Geometry Effect backward animation seems to be behind view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to use the matched geometry effect on a list and it is working like expected at least for the animation to the detail view.
The problem is that the animation back from the detail view to list list cell seems to be behind the list.

[image]

How can I get this working properly so that the detail view will shrink back to a list cell?
Here's the code for my cell:

```
struct Cell: View {

var exercise: Exercise
var index: Int
var namespace: Namespace.ID

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(exercise.title)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id, in: namespace)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .frame(height: 100)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .padding(.top)
    .padding(.bottom, 4)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id + "background", in: namespace)
            .background(Color.clear)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    )
    .clipped()
}
}
```

This is the list itself:

```
struct ListView: View {

var testData: [Exercise]
var namespace: Namespace.ID
@Binding var tappedCellIndex: Int?

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(testData.indices) { index in
                Cell(exercise: testData[index], index: index, namespace: namespace)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.8)) {
                        self.tappedCellIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let testData = [Exercise(title: "Hallo"), Exercise(title: "Bankdrücken"), Exercise(title: "Squats"), Exercise(title: "Seitheben"), Exercise(title: "Klimmzüge"), Exercise(title: "Bizepscurls"), Exercise(title: "Dips"), Exercise(title: "Aufroller"), Exercise(title: "Muscle"), Exercise(title: "Dragon Flies"), Exercise(title: "Hallo"), Exercise(title: "Bankdrücken"), Exercise(title: "Squats"), Exercise(title: "Seitheben"), Exercise(title: "Klimmzüge"), Exercise(title: "Bizepscurls"), Exercise(title: "Dips"), Exercise(title: "Aufroller"), Exercise(title: "Muscle"), Exercise(title: "Dragon Flies")]

@State var tappedCellIndex: Int? = nil
@Namespace var namespace

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            ListView(testData: testData, namespace: namespace, tappedCellIndex: $tappedCellIndex)
                .opacity(tappedCellIndex == nil ? 1 : 0)
                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
        }
        
        if let tappedCellIndex = tappedCellIndex {
            DetailView(exercise: testData[tappedCellIndex], selectedIndex: $tappedCellIndex, namespace: namespace)
                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the detail view from where it should animate back:

```
struct DetailView: View {

var exercise: Exercise
@Binding var selectedIndex: Int?
var namespace: Namespace.ID

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
            Text(exercise.title)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id, in: namespace)
                .font(.title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.top, 12)
            Spacer()
            Button {
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.8)) {
                    selectedIndex = nil
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Klicke hier!")
            }
        }

        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .padding()
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id + "background", in: namespace)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    )
}
}
```

And finally this is the model:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
var id = UUID().uuidString
var title: String

static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
}

}
```

sorry for that much code. I hope I added all that is needed.

btw: I also get the error "Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group". I think that is because I don't hide the list when displaying the detail view.
I read different opinions on this here on stackoverflow and it seems to me thats its not in every case necessary to hide one view when another one is displayed and I maybe can ignore the error message.

I also cant hide the list because a reload would refresh the list and I will start at the top of the list again so the backward animation also won't work.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: No, you just force remove details from view hierarchy instantly.

Comment: I recommend: https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/

Comment: @Asperi I see, thanks. I thought it should work with the selectedIndex = nil in the animation closure. Do you may have a suggestion what can I do differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. Just needed to set the zIndex for the DetailView like this..

```
if let tappedCellIndex = tappedCellIndex {
        DetailView(exercise: testData[tappedCellIndex], selectedIndex: $tappedCellIndex, namespace: namespace)
            .zIndex(1)
            .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
    }
```

Another thing that I needed to do is to remove the `.clipped()` from the Cell like ChrisR suggested. I didn't changed the order of the frame / matchedGeometryEffect modifier because that prevents a smooth animation in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend to show an empty placeholder to prevent "multiple inserted views". Also the `.frame(maxWidth, maxHeight)` has to come before the `.matchedGeometry`, so the view can shrink or grow in the animation.

[image]

Here is the amended code, check the comments:

```
struct Cell: View {
    
    var exercise: Exercise
    var index: Int
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(exercise.title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // moved + maxHeight!
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id, in: namespace)
        }
        .frame(height: 100) // moved
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
        .padding(.bottom, 4)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id + "background", in: namespace)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        )
        //    .clipped()
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    
    var testData: [Exercise]
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var tappedCellIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(testData.indices) { index in
                    // check if tapped
                    if index != tappedCellIndex {
                        Cell(exercise: testData[index], index: index, namespace: namespace)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.8)) {
                                    self.tappedCellIndex = index
                                }
                            }
                    } else { // display empty space
                        Color.clear
                            .frame(height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    let testData = [Exercise(title: "Hallo"), Exercise(title: "Bankdrücken"), Exercise(title: "Squats"), Exercise(title: "Seitheben"), Exercise(title: "Klimmzüge"), Exercise(title: "Bizepscurls"), Exercise(title: "Dips"), Exercise(title: "Aufroller"), Exercise(title: "Muscle"), Exercise(title: "Dragon Flies"), Exercise(title: "Hallo"), Exercise(title: "Bankdrücken"), Exercise(title: "Squats"), Exercise(title: "Seitheben"), Exercise(title: "Klimmzüge"), Exercise(title: "Bizepscurls"), Exercise(title: "Dips"), Exercise(title: "Aufroller"), Exercise(title: "Muscle"), Exercise(title: "Dragon Flies")]
    
    @State var tappedCellIndex: Int? = nil
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                ListView(testData: testData, namespace: namespace, tappedCellIndex: $tappedCellIndex)
                    .opacity(tappedCellIndex == nil ? 1 : 0)
                //                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
            }
            
            if let tappedCellIndex = tappedCellIndex {
                DetailView(exercise: testData[tappedCellIndex], selectedIndex: $tappedCellIndex, namespace: namespace)
                //                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    
    var exercise: Exercise
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int?
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(exercise.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // moved
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id, in: namespace)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.top, 12)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.8)) {
                        selectedIndex = nil
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Klicke hier!")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: exercise.id + "background", in: namespace)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        )
    }
}


struct Exercise: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, great information about the clear view. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I need the scale transition that you commented out because I don't want the fading effect when the view grows or shrinks. But for some reason I can't get it working with the scale transition. The grow animation just works fine but the shrink animation is somewhat behind the listview.

Comment: btw: your code only works with the .opacity(tappedCellIndex == nil ? 1 : 0) on the ListView. This is a leftover that I forgot to remove from the code, sorry. I actually don't want this. It would be nice when the cell gorws/shrinks with the listview completely visible behind it so that the listview also won't fade out/in